# What does recycling gift boxes mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The sentence is this:

> Winston spent Boxing Day recycling gift boxes, gift wrappings, and gift ribbons.

Is he repurposing them? Or is he disposing of them by throwing them in a designated trash bin?

Comment: It could mean either. You have not provided any context.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I thought maybe it's some Boxing Day-related ritual, which I'm unaware of, since I'm not familiar with the holiday. Anyway, I don't have any context to provide, but  your answer is appreciated.

Comment: I meant, where did you see this?

Comment: Have you looked up "recycle" in a dictionary?

Comment: Michael, it's from the book called "The Unofficial Harry Potter Vocabulary Builder" and all the information they provided on the matter in the book is this: Boxing Day (box-ing day)
noun A British holiday, the first weekday after Christmas. / Goblet of Fire, page 433
Winston spent Boxing Day recycling gift boxes, gift wrappings, and gift ribbons.

Comment: Oh dear. harry Potter. I do not wish to sound what may be an unpopular opinion, but some people think that the Harry Potter books are not great literature, and this goes double for the spin-off material, whether film, printed, or online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Boxing Day', the day after Christmas, is a holiday in the UK and a number of countries that previously formed part of the British Empire. If Christmas or Boxing Day or both fall on a weekend the holiday(s) happen after the weekend.

In the UK, most urban areas have compulsory segregation of household waste into separate containers or 'bins'. In my area we have six - a big bin with wheels for general waste, and smaller plastic bins for paper, cardboard, plastic, glass, and food waste. Informally, we might think of the act of putting those items into the right bin, ready for collection day, as 'recycling' them. We could also say that the actual recycling is done later, after the municipal truck has taken the waste away. So your sentence might mean that Winston spent the day sorting out some Christmas gift packaging waste into the various bins. If they were his, he must have received a lot of gifts if it took him all Boxing Day.

On the other hand, he could have spent the day making new things out of the materials, but this can also be called 'upcycling', to distinguish it from the above meaning.

There is not sufficient information to say which of these is meant.